# What is the default value of use_transactional_fixtures in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, database-cleaner

I am asking this because in the articles I have read so far, concerning rspec and the database_cleaner gem I see the line `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`. If I use the database_cleaner gem couldn't I just delete this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it In `rspec-core`:

```
  # Used internally and by extension frameworks like rspec-rails, so they
  # can add config settings that are domain specific. For example:
  #
  #     RSpec.configure do |c|
  #       c.add_setting :use_transactional_fixtures,
  #         :default => true,
  #         :alias_with => :use_transactional_examples
  #     end
```

So, default is `true`